# Get last message of Observable with RxJS

Tags: rxjs, observable

I was wondering whether is it possible to *replay* or *resend* the last message of an Observable in RxJS.

Like:

```
class MyClass {

    results: Observable<MyData[]>;
    first: MyData;

    reactToSmth() {
        this.results.subscribe((data: MyData[]) => {
            this.first = data[0];
        });
    }

    reactToSmthElse() {
        // doesn't exist :-)
        this.results.resendLast(data: MyData[]) => {
            this.first = data[1];
        });
    }

}
```

I know I can simply store `data` in my class so I can manipulate later, at the same time in a more complex case I would like to know if **is possible** to do something like that and how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, it is possible and even easy. There are several options, but the simplest for what you present is probably, giving `obs$` an observable, use `obs$.shareReplay(1)` to obtain an observable, which when subscribed to will reemit the last emitted value of `obs$`.